# What is the difference between metadata and page_content that make up a document in langchain?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I would like to search documents using langchain.
in langchain, when constructing a document, metadata and page_content properties exist.

When retrieving using langchain, does the content searched by query have to be included in metaData? Or should I put it in page_content?

```
docs = [
    Document(
        page_content="A bunch of scientists bring back dinosaurs and mayhem breaks loose",
        metadata={
            "year": 1993,
            "rating": 7.7,
            "director": "Steven Spielberg",
            "genre": "science fiction",
        },
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="Leo DiCaprio gets lost in a dream within a dream within a dream within a ...",
        metadata={
            "year": 2010,
            "director": "Christopher Nolan",
            "genre": "science fiction",
            "rating": 8.2,
        },
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="A psychologist / detective gets lost in a series of dreams within dreams within dreams and Inception reused the idea",
        metadata={
            "year": 2006,
            "director": "Satoshi Kon",
            "genre": "science fiction",
            "rating": 8.6,
        },
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="A bunch of normal-sized women are supremely wholesome and some men pine after them",
        metadata={
            "year": 2019,
            "director": "Greta Gerwig",
            "genre": "drama",
            "rating": 8.3,
        },
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="Toys come alive and have a blast doing so",
        metadata={
            "year": 1995,
            "director": "John Lasseter",
            "genre": "animated",
            "rating": 9.1,
        },
    ),
    Document(
        page_content="Three men walk into the Zone, three men walk out of the Zone",
        metadata={
            "year": 1979,
            "rating": 9.9,
            "director": "Andrei Tarkovsky",
            "genre": "science fiction",
        },
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to search documents that are embedded and ingested into a vector database using Langchain. Langchain utilizes its [retrieval](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/) for this purpose. In your case, it seems like you're employing the structure of a [Redis vector store](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/providers/redis) with key-value storage. In that case, you'd want to create an index using `langchain_community.vectorstores.redit` and combine that with some embeddings (e.g., OpenAI's `OpenAIEmbeddings`) so that you're able to create a vectorstore for your documents.

The code below is taken from [this notebook](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/retrievers/self_query/redis_self_query) from Langchain, which demonstrates the process and is based on the `docs` data that you've already included in your question:

```
index_schema = {
    "tag": [{"name": "genre"}],
    "text": [{"name": "director"}],
    "numeric": [{"name": "year"}, {"name": "rating"}],
}
vectorstore = Redis.from_documents(
    docs,
    embeddings,
    redis_url="redis://localhost:6379",
    index_name="movie_reviews",
    index_schema=index_schema,
)
```

You'd then be able to query it using a retriever, like so:

```
from langchain.chains.query_constructor.base import AttributeInfo
from langchain.retrievers.self_query.base import SelfQueryRetriever
from langchain_openai import OpenAI

metadata_field_info = [
    AttributeInfo(
        name="genre",
        description="The genre of the movie",
        type="string or list[string]",
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="year",
        description="The year the movie was released",
        type="integer",
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="director",
        description="The name of the movie director",
        type="string",
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="rating", description="A 1-10 rating for the movie", type="float"
    ),
]
document_content_description = "Brief summary of a movie"

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
retriever = SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
    llm, vectorstore, document_content_description, metadata_field_info, verbose=True
)
```

Then you can use the retriever to query over the ingested documents:

```
# This example only specifies a relevant query
retriever.get_relevant_documents("What are some movies about dinosaurs")
```